# sms on xcode (have MessageUI.framework), but still fail

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, sms

I reference this [website](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/how-to-send-an-sms-progammatically.html), I have `MessageUI.framework` in my frameworks file and I change it to the optional too. But I still get this error below:

> ld: warning: in /Users/mb/Desktop/tese/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI,
>   missing required architecture i386 in file Undefined symbols:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in OnlyForTest.o ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am a beginner and not very good at English, so please use simple words, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The `MessageUI.framework` works only on devices, not on simulators. The part about `missing required architecture i386` denotes that you are trying to use it on simulator.

If you want to avoid the crash on simulator, add the following check:

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    // do the display part
}
```